# pip commands return a TypeError

Tags: python, pip

I needed to install `hashlib` for one of my projects, and used `easy_install hashlib` (as was stated by [this Stack Exchange post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770262/python-hashlib-fails-to-install-pip)) to do so. However, right after I installed this package, I haven't been able to use pip at all. Whenever I type a command with `pip` (like `pip install`), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import random
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/hashlib.py", line 115, in <module>
    """
TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable
```

This also now occurs when I'm using `easy_install`- same error. I'm also not able to uninstall pip and reinstall- any command with `pip` results in the error above. Even executing

`pip --version` yields the same error. I know it's something to do with the `hashlib` package, but I'm not sure how to delete it and reinstall without messing up my entire Python configurations. My hypothesis is that the version of `hashlib` I installed is either too old or too new for my Python 2.7, and doesn't play well with it.

Does anyone know what exactly is going on behind the scenes here in this stack trace, and how I can fix `pip`?

Is the best thing to do to literally go in and delete `hashlib.py` from my `lib/python2.7` folder?

Comment: `hashlib` has been a standard module for ages, since Python 2.5. Why were you trying to install it?

Comment: @PM2Ring I was an idiot and thought it was some new dependency in my project. What's done is done.

Answer (score 0):

So, this doesn't solve the issue with `hashlib`, but it does get you a working `pip` again: literally download and reinstall Python 2.7 all over again [from the source](https://www.python.org/downloads/). If anyone comes up with a better, more elegant solution for fixing `pip`, I am all for it.

However, at least I can use `pip` again...

Comment: You seem to have a version mismatch -- you are running `/usr/local/bin/python` (presumably a Homebrew install?) against the MacOS default Python libraries in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Lib/python2.7`. I strongly suspect this is a duplicate question but not sure what exactly to search for.